# Hardware Print directly using Qt without using QPrintDialog

Tags: c++, linux, file, qt, printing

I need to hardware-print a pdf file (already existing file) on a button click.

It's like the file needed to print is already identified and present and upon clicking print button `QPushButton` this pdf file should be sent to printer queue without popping up a dialog for prinitng.

Is this possible with QPrinter or any other facility in Qt? (Platform is linux.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Qt has (as far as I know) no built-in way to do this. You need a program that understands how to convert PDF content into (for example) post-script to send to a printer.

A quick Google search came up with a library called "[Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)" that can render PDF content onto, say, `QImage` instances, and then you could print those.

That said, if you are restricting yourself to linux, you could just create a `QProcess` and call something like:

```
lp document.pdf
```

Comment: The problem is I have to run this binary on ARM-platform, So I have to cross compile Poppler module and statically link it while cross-compiling which further increase the size of binary. Nevertheless thanks for your idea, I can use system call for this purpose [System("lpr filename")].

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 5.2, I was able to use these functions to convert HTML -> WebView -> Print()
Originally, I was thinking of printing PDF directly, but this did the job. (And most of this code was gathered from other sites or forums)

```
void MainWindow::on_btnHtmltoWebView_clicked()
{
    QString html = ui->txtHtml->toPlainText();
    ui->webView->setHtml(html);
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(3);
}

void MainWindow::on_btnPrintWebView_clicked()
{
    QPrinter p;
    p.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    p.setFullPage(false);
    p.setResolution(100);
    p.setFromTo(0,1);   //only print 1 page
    p.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    QString printerName = QPrinterInfo::defaultPrinter().printerName();
    ui->webView->print(&p);
    showTrayMessage("Printing" ,"Output format: "+ QString::number(p.outputFormat()) +
                     QString("Printer state: ") + QString::number(p.printerState())
                    );
}
```