# Printing receipts with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qprinter

I'm working on a cashier application using python and I want to print receipts directly without printer dialog (I'm using a usb printer). I would also like to control the layout of paper printed.

My code so far:

```
def createPrinteDialog(self):
    try:
        bill = ""
        for i in range(len(dig.bill)):
            bill += dig.bill.item(i).text() + "\n"

        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            dig.textEdit.setText(bill)
            dig.textEdit.print_(printer)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

However, this doesn't work very well. It prints receipts that are too long and the font is too small. The printer dialog also comes up every time.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

ok, the dialog problem solved when i deleted 
`if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:`

but now i want to control the lay out of paper printed

Comment: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/66331-QPrinter-without-QPrintDialog

Comment: [hardware-print-directly-using-qt-without-using-qprintdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635860/hardware-print-directly-using-qt-without-using-qprintdialog)  - you need to translate it tp python though